# Dynamic symbol generation with SymPy

Tags: python, algorithm, math, sympy

I recently asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4280577/) question about solving a system of nonlinear equations, over on Math SE. I am now attempting to implement the accepted answer using `SymPy` in `Python`. I'll begin by briefly recreating the solution here.

---

**Problem.**

Suppose I have three receivers, with coordinates given by vectors `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`. Further, I have a transmitter, emitting radio pulses at unknown times `t1, t2, t3, t4, ...` with known speed `c`, and which has unknown initial coordinates at time `t = t1` given by the vector `x0 = <x,y,z>` and is moving with an unknown *constant* velocity given by the vector `v`. My data consists of the pulse arrival time at each station, denoted `air` (for arrival of time of signal `i` at receiver `r`).

My goal is to determine this velocity. The solution given in the attached answer is as follows:

> The position of the transmitter at time `t` will be given by `xo = v(t - t1)`. Hence, the distance between the transmitter and the `rth` receiver at the time the `ith` pulse is emitted will be given by:
>
> `||(ti - t1)v + x0 - pr||`
>
> Therefore, the time of arrival at the `rth` receiver is given by:
>
> `ti + (1/c) * ||(ti - t1)v + x0 - pr||`
>
> Which we know to be `air`. Therefore:
>
> `c**2(air - ti)**2 = ||v||**2(ti - t1)**2 + 2(ti -t1)<v, c0 - pr>`
>
> (where `<a, b>` denotes the scalar/dot product of vectors `a` and
> `b`).
>
> This results in a system of `# receivers x # pulses` equations.

(see the attached answer for far nicer formatting)

---

**Implementation.**

I'm most familiar with the `SymPy` package, so I'm attempting to implement a solution using its solvers. I'm a bit stuck, however, on where to begin.

The number of pulses is not known before hand thus, as `SymPy` is a symbolic solver, I must be able to dynamically define variables `t1, t2, t3... tn`.

My rough outline for an implementation is as follows:

```
import sympy as sp

def find_transmitter(arrival_times):
    equations = []

    for receiver in arrival_times:
        for pulse in arrival_times:
            equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - ti...

    sp.solve(equations...
```

Where `arrival_times` is a list, where each column corresponds to a receiver, and each row corresponds to a pulse. I.e.:

```
[[a11, a21, a31...],[a12, a22, a32...],[a13, a23, a33...]]
```

It doesn't occur to me that there's a nice alternative to this approach. I'm not sure, however, e.g. how to dynamically define enough `ti`'s and iterate through them. That is, e.g., I'll have an unknown number of equations looking like:

```
equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - t1...
equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - t2...
equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - t3...
equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - t4...
equations.append(sp.Eq(c**2(pulse - t5...
.
.
.
```

Is there a nice way to do this? Very likely, I'm overlooking some obvious solution.

Comment: If `arival_times` is large I'd expect very long `sympy.solve` times.  `sympy` doesn't scale as well as numeric solvers (`numpy` and `scipy`).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps surprisingly, can dynamically create any number of symbols with `symbols` using space as a delimiter!

You can also subscript with `_N`

```py
arrival_times_count = 100  # from data length
chunksize = 10  # some factor of arrival_times_count

def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

from sympy import *
# create a huge collection
collection = symbols(" ".join(f"t_{x}" for x in range(arrival_times_count)), real=True)
# fold it into rows
collection = list(chunks(collection, chunksize))
```

```py
>>> for row in collection:
...     print(row)
...
(t_0, t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4, t_5, t_6, t_7, t_8, t_9)
(t_10, t_11, t_12, t_13, t_14, t_15, t_16, t_17, t_18, t_19)
(t_20, t_21, t_22, t_23, t_24, t_25, t_26, t_27, t_28, t_29)
(t_30, t_31, t_32, t_33, t_34, t_35, t_36, t_37, t_38, t_39)
(t_40, t_41, t_42, t_43, t_44, t_45, t_46, t_47, t_48, t_49)
(t_50, t_51, t_52, t_53, t_54, t_55, t_56, t_57, t_58, t_59)
(t_60, t_61, t_62, t_63, t_64, t_65, t_66, t_67, t_68, t_69)
(t_70, t_71, t_72, t_73, t_74, t_75, t_76, t_77, t_78, t_79)
(t_80, t_81, t_82, t_83, t_84, t_85, t_86, t_87, t_88, t_89)
(t_90, t_91, t_92, t_93, t_94, t_95, t_96, t_97, t_98, t_99)
```

`chunks` function from [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

---

However, there's a good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you may be better off doing something like packing your data into a [pandas.DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), [lambdifying](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) your equation, and then calling [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to find the result of each row

Answer (score 1):

A **dirty** way to dynamically define variables is to make a string pattern (with python code) and then process it with `exec`. So you can have access to the variables without passing though list, tuples, ...  The best way would be to use substitution (vector -> components), hence you work with a vector & lambdify to perform componentwise operations.

```
from sympy import *
n = 4
t_s = ( ''.join((i, str(j))) for i, j in  zip('t'*n, range(1, n+1)))
exec( f"{', '.join(t_s)}  = symbols('t1:{n+1}')")

print(t2, type(t2))
```

Output

```
t2 <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

Comment: honestly, dynamically creating sympy names/expressions is a great candidate for all sorts of eccentric `exec()` calls and really they go very well together and are something other languages don't have as easy!

Comment: ...but you can fall also easily in your own trap if you are not careful! For example, `t0` will give raise error because the variables start at 1 and this is not very readable in the source code

Comment: of course! still, you can inspect the state with _more evil_ like `set(globals().keys()) - previously_saved_keys` and `NameError` is easy to understand and handle!